# Чтение дерева JSON запроса API на Python

Tags: python, json, парсер

Хочу разобраться в чтении JSON на Python. Хочу получить все NAME (Steve_01, _02, _03), но пока что мне удалось получить "MAX" "NOW" "SAMPLE"

Подскажите пожалуйста, что в коде не так.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('ССЫЛКА API')
json_data = response.json() if response and response.status_code == 200 else None
for product in json_data['players']:
  print(product) //выводит max now sample
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for product in json_data['players']['sample']:
    print(producх['name'])
print([х['name'] for x in json_data['players']['sample']])
```